# "significado" vs. "significación"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

When would one use `significado` and when `significación`?

What are the nuances of meaning of these two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is quite an advanced concept. In linguistics, *significado* is the word's meaning and *significación* is the graphical representation of a concept, in other words, the word itself.

*Significación* can also refer to something's value: *Un lugar de gran significación histórica*.

Comment: You are right, but personally, I never use significación, I can't remember last time I did :o. I think you explanation maybe is a bit hard for a non native speaker, with the example is clear for me, but maybe is not for non-native speaker.

Comment: Significacion in the sense of value is sometimes used in books, documentaries and so on. Significacion as the graphical representation of a concept is a term we use in philology

Comment: para ser honesto es la primera vez q leo eso de "significación".... en tu ejemplo por ejemplo yo diría... Un lugar de gran significado histórico.... en fin... gracias por el ejemplo

Answer (score 5):

**Significado** is the "meaning", "sense", "concept" or "notion" that acquires a symbol or any object that can be interpreted. Is the mental concept that is "transported" in a word, a gesture, an action, etc.

In Chile **significación** means "importance", "value", "magnitude", probably influenced by the adjective "significativo". I don't know if used in other countries with that sense. Ex:

> El acercamiento de la oposición es un gesto de enorme **significación** para el gobierno.

Otherwise, in lingüistics, "significación" is the mental process of generation/understanding of signs by pairing a signifier with a meaning. Therefore the next sentence is correct, although its use is highly technical:

> La **significación** es el proceso de generar signos asignando un **significado** a un significante.

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker, I have to say I barely use *significación*. I always favor *significado* to convey "the meaning" of something.

"Significación" sounds to me like "creating the sign or representation of something", although it seems that it can be also used as a synonym of "significado". I googled "significación" up and I found [this site](http://definicion.de/significacion/), which has an interesting description:

> Un signo lingüístico es la unidad mínima de la oración que está formada por un significado y un significante. Ambos se encuentran unidos en forma inseparable a través de la significación. **Puede decirse que el significado es un concepto**, mientras que el significante es una imagen acústica: **la significación es la entidad de dos caras interdependientes que crean este concepto con su imagen acústica**.

So this means that when you hear or read "dog" (a word is the minimum linguistic sign in a sentence) you associate that written word or sound to an animal. *Significado* would be what the word means. *Significación* would be giving a representation as a word or sign to the "dog entity".